# FileSystemWatcher getting Invalid memory access error

Tags: .net, filesystemwatcher

I have a strange problem with a FileSystemWatcher.

It's getting an "Invalid access to memory location" Win32Exception passed into its Error event handler.  This exception has no stack trace, so I can't see where the error is happening, but it must be part of the watcher itself.
When this happens, the watcher stops responding and I don't get any more events until I restart it.

The only thing close to this error I was able to find via Google is if it runs out of memory or if changes happen faster than they can get processed. But this happens fairly quickly after the program is started and memory is not an issue yet and the few events that happen before the Error event are handled quickly.

I don't know if this is relevant, but I'm usually watching a UNC path or a mapped network drive.
**EDIT:**  I have verified that this is *only* a problem for network shares.  It works fine on local drives.

This code has been around for years and just started having this issue a couple months ago.  I wouldn't rule out an infrastructure change or Windows update causing it, but I'm looking for ways to diagnose what's causing it.

**EDIT:**  Here's a stripped-down version of what it's doing (VB.NET)

```vb
Private Class Watcher
    Implements IDisposable

    Private WithEvents _FileSystemWatcher As IO.FileSystemWatcher

    Sub New(directory As String)
        _FileSystemWatcher = New IO.FileSystemWatcher
        _FileSystemWatcher.Path = directory
        _FileSystemWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub _FileSystemWatcher_FileSystemEvent(source As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs) Handles _FileSystemWatcher.Created, _FileSystemWatcher.Changed, _FileSystemWatcher.Deleted
        ' removed for brevity - For the purposes of this problem, it 
        ' is irrelevant.  We get the error even if there are no events here.
    End Sub

    Private Sub _FileSystemWatcher_Error(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As ErrorEventArgs) Handles _FileSystemWatcher.Error
        Dim ex = e.GetException()
        If ex IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim win32ex = TryCast(ex, System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception)
            ' At this point, win32ex.NativeErrorCode will be 998 for the
            ' Invalid Memory Access
        End If
    End Sub

    ' Dispose implementation removed for brevity on StackOverflow post,
    ' but it disposes the _FileSystemWatcher.

End Class
```

Comment: I had a similar problem, turned out that the `FileWatcher` was a private field that the garbage collection recycled - I'd get all kinds of errors. Maybe a newer .NET JIT is now *smarter*. I ended up using polling with a `System.Threading.Timer` because I couldn't get `FileWatcher` to work consistently. I'd wager that it is just a thin wrapper over some 30 year old Windows API so I'm not too surprised that it's not a good citizen in managed code land :-)

Comment: It is a *very* nasty error, occurs when the DllMain() entrypoint of a DLL crashes with an AccessViolationException.  Why FSW is loading a DLL is quite hard to guess, maybe it has something to do with the code you run in an event handler.  Could be anti-malware falling over perhaps.  You left no clue whatsoever, not even the minimal code snippet we normally demand here.  Only diagnosable by using an unmanaged debugger and forcing it to stop on the first-chance exception.

Comment: Taking mfeineis's suggestion, I tried implementing the Finalize method and put breakpoints there and in Dispose and neither one are getting called.  I can see in the error event handler that the watcher's private disposed and IsHandleInvalid are both false